# Why can't I return a variable of type List<List<int>> for a function that has a IList<IList<int>> return type in C#

Tags: c#, interface, covariance

```
public IList<IList<int>> FunctionName(...)
{
    var list = new List<List<int>>();
    ...
    //return list;                      // This doesn't compile (error listed below)
    return (IList<IList<int>>)list;     // Explicit cast compiles
}
```

When I return "list" directly, I get this error:

```
> "Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>'
> to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IList<int>>'.
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
```

Shouldn't an interface return type accept any derived instance?

Comment: It worked for me :/. Can you give us more details about framework and language version?

Comment: *“Shouldn't an interface return type accept any derived instance?”* – Yes, but the interface type of `List<List<int>>` is `IList<List<int>>`. Because `List<T>` implements `IList<T>`. It says nothing about the type conversion of different `T`s inside. That’s handled by [covariance and contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Comment: @Misters: What language version are you using?  I've never seen a c# compiler that would allow that.

Comment: Tried targeting both .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.0, same error :/

Answer (score 6):

There's a subtle type error.  If this worked, you'd have the potential of having these kinds of errors.

```
List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>();
IList<IList<int>> ilist = list;  // imagine a world where this was legal

// This is already allowed by the type system
ilist.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });

// This is actually an array! Not a List<>
List<int> first = list[0];
```

You might be able to satisfy your requirements by using `IReadOnlyList<>`.  Since it's read only, that type error is unable to manifest in code.  But you can never add elements or update values in the outer list.  This feature of generic interfaces is called "covariance".

```
IReadOnlyList<IList<int>> ilist = list;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the function signature dictates that I need to return IList<IList<int>>, while inside the function I do need to add items to the list to construct it (so I cannot make it readonly). Any way around it?

Comment: @breezeZ: There a  number of ways to do it if you're willing to make a new list.  For one, you can call `.ToList()` on the final `ilist` and get what you want.